# What's the associative rule of infix operator in Scala pattern match

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, infix-operator

I can't organize properly to describe the real question it is. But those examples I think it's enough:
There are some definition class and object here,

```
  case class ?(a: String, b: Int)
  case class MatchA(a: String, b: Int)

  object MatchInt {// can't
    def unapply(arg: Int): Option[(Long, Double)] = {
      Some(arg, arg)
    }
  }
  object & {// or :? or ?: or +& or +
    def unapply(arg: Int): Option[(Long, Double)] = {
      Some(arg, arg)
    }
  }
```

#### Example1, the normal usage of infix extract with a brackets at `(b MatchInt c)`:

```
  @Test
  def matchOK1(): Unit = {
    MatchA("abc", 123) match {
      case a MatchA (b MatchInt c) =>
        println(s"$a, $b, $c")
    }

  }
```

#### Example2, no brackets in `b` and `c` but need a special extractor name definition with `&` or `:?` or `?:` or `+&` or `+`, maybe others.

```
  @Test
  def matchOK2(): Unit = {
    MatchA("abc", 123) match {
      case a MatchA b & c =>
        println(s"$a, $b, $c")
    }
  }
```

#### Example3, fail example

```
  @Test
  def matchFail1(): Unit = {
    MatchA("abc", 123) match {
      case a MatchA b MatchInt c =>
        println(s"$a, $b, $c")
    }

  }
```

two error occurred:

```
pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
[error]  found   : Int
[error]  required: Match.this.MatchA
[error]       case a MatchA b MatchInt c =>
[error]                       ^
```

and

```
constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
[error]  found   : Match.this.MatchA
[error]  required: Long
[error]       case a MatchA b MatchInt c =>
[error]              ^
[error] two errors found
```

Besides, the error message is very confusing.

#### Example4, error message similar as former

```
 @Test
  def matchFail2(): Unit = {
    ?("abc", 123) match {
      case a ? b & c =>
        println(s"$a, $b, $c")
    }

  }
```

Is there are special rules under the name of extractor that could effect the pattern match?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern expression is parsed just the same as a normal expression.

(Outside a pattern, you get `apply`, inside a pattern, you get `unapply`.)

The rules for associativity and precedence are [in the spec](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#infix-operations).

Operators are higher precedence than alnum identifiers.

That's why your example 2 works, but I guess you don't like that syntax.

Comment: Thanks, I'm saw the usage at http4s route DSL, like `a :? b +& c` to parse part of url's parameter. It's useful at such place ;-)

Comment: I really dislike the precedence setting which decide by first char. It will generate many strange token in DSL.As for url DSL, `?` and `&` is just fine.